# How to use list component (c:list) in PDFReporter for Android?

Tags: android, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I have used iReport to print pdf by JasperReports.

However when I try to use PDFReporter to print pdf for Android it's not work.

```
<componentElement>
            <reportElement x="215" y="30" width="110" height="50" uuid="2a10bb8c-3e40-4669-886a-22cdd9a11216"/>
            <c:list xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="c27c01dc-9026-40c5-8c8f-4b1090d99cf9">
                    <!--<><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></>-->
                </datasetRun>
                <c:listContents height="50" width="110">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="43" y="17" width="100" height="30" uuid="a190eb91-8dfa-476e-afcb-3336ac79ac99"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Child_1_Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </c:listContents>
            </c:list>
        </componentElement>
```

This is an error:

```
08-02 14:09:44.219 2498-2788/com.csc.ipos E/Digester: Begin event threw exception
  org.oss.pdfreporter.exception.ConversionException: Cannot set Property schemaLocation on Object org.oss.pdfreporter.components.list.StandardListComponent@309039c1
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.beans.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:35)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.beans.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:100)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:240)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.AbstractRule.begin(AbstractRule.java:65)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.impl.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:176)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.xml.parsers.wrapper.UnmarshallingContentHandler.startElement(UnmarshallingContentHandler.java:56)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.startElement(ExpatParser.java:143)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:513)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:316)
      at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.xml.parsers.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:49)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.impl.Digester.parse(Digester.java:373)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.DelegatingAbstractDigester.parse(DelegatingAbstractDigester.java:84)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:241)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:215)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.loadReport(PdfReporter.java:315)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.exportSqlReport(PdfReporter.java:176)
      at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.exportPdf(PdfReporter.java:152)
      at com.csc.ipos.pdfexporter.ReportExporter.exportUsingXMLDatasource(ReportExporter.java:88)
      at com.csc.ipos.TestPDFExportActivity$3.run(TestPDFExportActivity.java:99)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: schemaLocation
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:886)
```

After that I try to delete schemaLocation property, but it throw an another error:

```
E/Digester: Begin event threw exception
org.oss.pdfreporter.exception.ConversionException: Cannot set Property width on Object org.oss.pdfreporter.components.list.DesignListContents@2525b0fd
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.beans.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:35)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.beans.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:100)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:240)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.AbstractRule.begin(AbstractRule.java:65)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.impl.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:176)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.xml.parsers.wrapper.UnmarshallingContentHandler.startElement(UnmarshallingContentHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.startElement(ExpatParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:513)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:316)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.xml.parsers.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:49)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.impl.Digester.parse(Digester.java:373)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.apache.digester.DelegatingAbstractDigester.parse(DelegatingAbstractDigester.java:84)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:241)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:215)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.loadReport(PdfReporter.java:315)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.exportSqlReport(PdfReporter.java:176)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.PdfReporter.exportPdf(PdfReporter.java:152)
    at com.csc.ipos.pdfexporter.ReportExporter.exportUsingXMLDatasource(ReportExporter.java:88)
    at com.csc.ipos.TestPDFExportActivity$3.run(TestPDFExportActivity.java:99)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field org.oss.pdfreporter.components.list.DesignListContents.width has type java.lang.Integer, got java.lang.String
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:557)
    at org.oss.pdfreporter.beans.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:33)
```

It also happened with height property of listcontent component.

Note: I added the statement below in "jasperreports_extension.properties"

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.components=org.oss.pdfreporter.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory
```

Comment: Have you read my question? It's exactly for Android and focus on c:list.
Beside that, "subDataset1" it is not important in this case.
Have you ever use PDFRporter? It's is not easy to use like JasperReport.
Some feature PDFReporter doesn't support such as (chart, bar code, table ...) But when I read the source code of PDFReporter, I see it can use "list" but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Petter Friberg
I edited my question. I hope it clearer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah much better, now other users can see if they have same problem, I will see if I can find something that can help you.

Comment: Try to use this definition `<c:list xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">`

Comment: @Petter Friberg
Thank for your help, but it still appears the same error

Comment: I can solve this issue by another solution by using "subreport".
By this way, I can create table, list for PDFReporter but it takes a lot of time to design the template. 
As I say before I see that PDFrepoter maybe can support for list so I prefer to use list component if I can.